# Not able to parse webpage contents using beautiful soup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have been using Beautiful Soup for parsing webpages for some data extraction. It has worked perfectly well for me so far, for other webpages. But however I'm trying to count the number of < a> tags in this [page](http://www.dnaindia.com/cricket?page=89),

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
catsection = "cricket"
url_base = "http://www.dnaindia.com/"
i = 89

url = url_base + catsection + "?page=" + str(i)
print(url)

#This is the page I'm trying to parse and also the one in the hyperlink
#I get the correct url i'm looking for at this stage

r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

j=0
for num in soup.find_all('a'):
    j=j+1
print(j)
```

I'm getting the output as 0. This makes me think that the 2 lines after r=requests.get(url) is probably not working(there's obviously no chance that there's zero < a> tags in the page), and i'm not sure about what alternative solution I can use here. Does anybody have any solution or faced a similar kind of problem before? 
Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass some of the information along with the request to the server.
Following code should work...You can play along with other parameter as well

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
catsection = "cricket"
url_base = "http://www.dnaindia.com/"
i = 89

url = url_base + catsection + "?page=" + str(i)
print(url)

headers = {
    'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'
}

#This is the page I'm trying to parse and also the one in the hyperlink
#I get the correct url i'm looking for at this stage

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

j=0
for num in soup.find_all('a'):
    j=j+1
print(j)
```

Comment: That worked for me correctly, thanks a lot @shogo2022 !

Answer (score 0):

Put any url in the parser and check the number of "a" tags available on that page:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url_base = "http://www.dnaindia.com/cricket?page=1"
res = requests.get(url_base, headers={'User-agent': 'Existed'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
a_tag = soup.select('a')
print(len(a_tag))
```