# BeautifulSoup requests gets HTML frame but unable to access elements

Tags: beautifulsoup

Currently I'm running on a VRM using ubuntu; so I'm trying to scrape data from an e-commerce web as a test. So far, I'm able to load the HTML contents; but I can't access any of the tags. I've checked other similar post to this problem by including a header; etc

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://shopee.com.my/'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0'}

response = get(url, headers=headers)
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')


def findDiv():
    for container in html_soup.find_all('div'):
        print(container)
        print(container.div)
        #returns None#

print(findDiv())
```

However, it still won't load anything other than two div tags, which is `<main>` & `<modal>`
[Similar Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45804572/not-able-to-parse-webpage-contents-using-beautiful-soup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dynamic page you have to use **Selenium** or use Bot user-agent for `requests`, to inspect the element install Chrome extension to change user-agent or save the page source

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)'}
response = get(url, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Yup, that solved it. Using the Bot user-agent. Thanks to you a bunch :)